# if we apply some properties in both html and css code which one will apply first and which will be finally applied

Tags: html, css

I need to know if we apply some properties in both html and css for same elements ,
 which one of these will be finally applied to the display and why ...

Comment: by the meaning of "CSS", style="x" over style in html over css file. But some rules will apply first by the detail degree of that rule, or the !important properpty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inline`-styles in a document have the highest priority, so for example say if you want to change the color of a `div` element to blue, but you've an `inline` style with a color property set to `red`.

```
<div style="font-size: 18px; color: red;">
   Hello World, How Can I Change The Color To Blue?
</div>

div {
   color: blue; 
   /* This Won't Work, As Inline Styles Have Color Red And As 
      Inline Styles Have Highest Priority, We Cannot Over Ride 
      The Color Using An Element Selector */
}
```

if you want to apply external css definition then here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/Z7D9k/)

use `!important`, note, `!important` is important here, else it won't over ride the inline styles..

> Note: Using !important ONLY will work here, but I've used div[style]
>   selector to specifically select div having style attribute

[Here Is](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)  a full details about all you want.